# different result from sumx function when applied on virtual table and calculated table in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

CASE 1:-

```
I have created one calculated table using below code.

OverallUtilisation = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
Mergetable[CalculateDateFromUTC],FILTER(Mergetable,Mergetable[noShow]<>"TRUE"),
"OverallResourceDistCount", DISTINCTCOUNT(Mergetable[fkItemID]),
"OverallDuration(Hours)", SUMX(Mergetable,Mergetable[MeetingDurationInHours]))

OverallUtilisation Table 

CalculateDateFromUTC    OverallResourceDistCount    OverallDuration(Hours)
16-06-2021 00:00:00                 1                     0.25
17-06-2021 00:00:00                 1                     2.01666666666667
03-11-2020 00:00:00                 1                     0.5
14-09-2020 00:00:00                 1                     0.25
15-09-2020 00:00:00                 1                     2.75
04-08-2021 00:00:00                 1                     0.25
12-08-2021 00:00:00                 1                     0.25


applied maxx function to get measure of OverallDuration(Hours) and code given below.

MAXDURHRSTEST = MAXX(OverallUtilisation,OverallUtilisation[OverallDuration(Hours)])
result MAXDURHRSTEST = 2.75
```

CASE 2:-

I have tried to get the result in single dax query. Code and result given below. i am bit confused why i am getting the different result while i am using same code and logic. can anyone explain me what is wrong in my code or logic. it will be great help for me.

```
MAXYY = 
VAR OverallUtilisationYY = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
Mergetable[CalculateDateFromUTC],FILTER(Mergetable,Mergetable[noShow]<>"TRUE"),
"OverallResourceDistCount", DISTINCTCOUNT(Mergetable[fkItemID]),
"OverallDuration(Hours)", SUMX(Mergetable,Mergetable[MeetingDurationInHours]))
RETURN
MAXX(OverallUtilisationYY,[OverallDuration(Hours)])
result MAXYY = 0.75
```

Comment: The key difference between the calculated and virtual tables is that the virtual table is affected by the filters in your report, while calculated table is not.

Comment: why am i getting different result?

Comment: As I said, in case 2 the virtual table is filtered, so your calculations are based on a subset of data, while in case 1 they are based on all data.

Comment: Can i do this  using single dax query with different approach, i want filters need to work?@RADO